# Get input value via v-on:change and click in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with code in vuejs :

**template :**

```html
<b-form-input
   placeholder="name"
   type="text"
   class="d-inline-block"
   v-model="name"
   v-on:change="changeInput"
/>
<b-button
   variant="primary"
   class="btn-tour-finish"
   @click="getValue()"
   >
</b-button>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    name: '',
  }
}
methods: {
 getValue() {
   console.log(this.name)
 },
 changeInput() {
   console.log(this.name)
 },
}
```

Here when i `click` on button i get input value or I enter via `v-on:change` event also get input value. But the problem here is i have to process twice in the methods with the same code. (`@click` and `v-on: change`). is there a way to combine `@click` and `v-on:change` into one function in methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so:

```
<b-form-input
   placeholder="name"
   type="text"
   class="d-inline-block"
   v-model="name"
   @keyup.enter="changeValue"
/>
<b-button
   variant="primary"
   class="btn-tour-finish"
   @click="changeValue"
   >
</b-button>

data() {
  return {
    name: '',
  }
}
methods: {
 changeValue() {
   console.log(this.name)
 },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the same code with functions

```
data() {
  return {
    name: '',
  }
}
methods: {
 getValue() {
   this.handle()
 },
 changeInput() {
   this.handle()
 },
 handle() {
   console.log(this.name)
 },
}
```

Comment: if you do that, then when the button is clicked, it will be called value twice..that is `v-on:change` and `click`. is there any other way

Comment: How about this `v-on:change="handle"` `@click="handle"`

Comment: When enter input one result is shown..but when button is clicked it will show two results of `v-on:change` and `click`.

Comment: Is the above your complete code? Did you change the `name` in the `getValue` function?

Comment: Above is my complete code.. I want to press enter then through v-on:change event get value of input.. And when click button it also get input value but use same function, and now it's doubled

Comment: https://files.fm/u/by8q8vkxa#/view/9czfeqnek.  When i @click it will output double

Comment: Replace `@change` with `@keyup.enter` https://x483z.csb.app/

Comment: I replaced `@change` with `@key-enter`, when I press the button click, it doesn't show double.. But when I press input enter, it doubles. Where did I go wrong?